# Access Kindle files sent via the special email address?

Tags: kindle

If I send a file to my kindle via the special email address, is it possible for me to copy those files off of my kindle via USB? (with or without hacking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The Kindle appears as a removable drive when plugged in by USB.

Answer (score 1):

When sending files to your special kindle email address, you will also receive a mail to your registered (normal) email address, with instructions and the link to the file. You can download the file using the link provided and transfer it to your Kindle with USB.